# Reformat date Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Looking for the best way to convert a string like `"01/16/2016"` into a friendly date format that rails can handle.

I have a calendar in which users can select a `from_date` and a `to_date`.. based on those params, my search will then filter results that fit the time periods.

Unfortunately, rails cannot handle the current format its in. Not sure the best way to go about this. I could change the search form's javascript to display the date differently, but I feel this format is most user friendly.

thx!

Comment: Why don't you use date as data_type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard ruby `Date` class:

```
some_date = Date.strptime('01/16/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

some_date will be an instance of `Date`, which then you can handle in rails and reformat in any way you want using `strftime`.

Answer (score 1):

As like taglia said you can use the strptime

```
Date.strptime('01/16/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

You can change the calendar date format from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy, then you can use

```
require 'date'
date = DateTime.parse("16/01/2016")
=> #<DateTime: 2016-01-16T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457404j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
=> "Sat Jan 16 00:00:00 +00:00 2016"
```

You can use Date instead of DateTime if you want only the date.